# How to Show/Hide Android FlowingDrawer via code?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to show or hide this drawer via Code?

I'm trying to add custom hamburger button.

==
here is the link of drawer library that I'm using

https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer

== and here's the same question on its page

https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer/issues/56

Comment: Did you try the [`FlowingDrawer#openMenu(boolean)`](https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer/blob/master/flowingdrawer-core/src/main/java/com/mxn/soul/flowingdrawer_core/FlowingDrawer.java#L36) and [`closeMenu(boolean)`](https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer/blob/master/flowingdrawer-core/src/main/java/com/mxn/soul/flowingdrawer_core/FlowingDrawer.java#L55) methods?

Answer (score 0):

@ Mike M commented

Did you try the FlowingDrawer#openMenu(boolean) and closeMenu(boolean) methods?

```
drawer.openMenu(true);
```